# node-red - Metrics display with pm2?

Tags: monitoring, node-red, nodejs

The Node-RED [documentation](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/logging) is clear - set `metrics` to `true` to track  flow execution and memory usage information. So, I stopped Node-RED with `pm2`, edited the `settings.js` file and started Node-RED. But, no metric output is seen in the `.pm2/logs/red-out-1.log`! The debug nodes in various flows in my application have been configured to output to console and they come correctly.

How to view the metrics?

Comment: Which settings file did you edit? Make sure it's the one in your userdir (pointed to in the first few lines of the Node-RED output at startup

Comment: Also what version of Node-RED are you running?

Comment: `node_modules/node-red/settings.js` and version is `node-red@0.18.7` from `package.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have edited the wrong `settings.js` file. The version in the `node_modules/node-red` directory is the template that gets copied to the User directory when Node-RED is started for the very first time.

When Node-RED starts it logs the settings file it is using as follows:

```
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [info] Settings file  : /home/hardillb/.node-red/settings.js
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [info] User directory : /home/hardillb/.node-red
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [warn] Projects disabled : set editorTheme.projects.enabled=true to enable
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [info] Flows file     : /home/hardillb/.node-red/flows_tiefighter.json
21 Jul 13:31:49 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
```

Comment: Yes, I had edited the wrong one; it works now. Thanks!